# Trying to hide UITableViewCell separator by using insets but it only decreases in opacity

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to hide a UITableViewCell's separator by pushing it all the way to the right as far as it goes. So I set both the cell's [separator inset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvHoT.png) and [layout margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XSed.png) all the way to the right as far as they go. But this only makes the cell [slightly more transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9KrU.png). As you see in the picture, the lower line is slightly more transparent than the one above. There seems to be another line for the cell below the one I hide that I can't remove for some reason. No idea what could be causing this.

Comment: self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the separators by calling `table.separatorStyle = .None` on your UITableView.

Edit 2: I couldn't tell by the question that the goal was to remove cell separators for just one type of cell: as mentioned in my comment below, I'd advise removing the separators with the line above and adding a small-height `UIView` as a custom separator where you want it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to hide the separator just for this cell type.

Comment: Then I would consider hiding the separators for all of them as above, and using a UIView with small height as a custom separator in the other cell type(s) that should have a separator.

Answer (score 2):

Hide tableview seperator simply by setting its property in attribute inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the Attributes inspector and set seperator = none if you want to hide then otherwise if you want to do any operation with seperator color then set color on there.

Answer (score 0):

UITabieViewCell generally contain two subviews: content view and separator line. If a cell's height is 44.f, content view's height is 43.f and 1.f for the line. You just move the line away, but the height of it is still there.

Comment: ps: If you want some of the cells without separator line, the better way is `table.separatorStyle = .None` and draw the line yourself in the cells.

Comment: Oh.. that's helpful. But why do other cells work perfectly fine? This only happens with the last cell.